# ReferenceError: self is not defined in next js while forking child process via custom webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, fork

I am trying to fork a child process in next js for time consuming operation. For that, here is my webpack config (`next.config.js`):

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {

    if (isServer) {
      return merge(config, {
        entry () {
          return config.entry().then((entry) => {
            return Object.assign({}, entry, { 'collection.worker': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'workers/collection.worker.ts') })
          })
        }
      });
    } else {
      return config;
    }
  }
};
```

My collection.worker.ts file:

```
const sleep = require('await-sleep');
const paymentId = process.argv[2];

(async () => {
  // DO WORK HERE
  console.log("doing work ", paymentId);
  await sleep(10000);
  console.log("Done!");
})();

// tslint:disable-next-line: no-empty
const noop = () => {};

export default noop;
```

Heres my `src/pages/api/hello.ts` endpoint:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import {getServerSession} from "next-auth";
import authOptions from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";
import {fork} from "child_process";

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
  fork("./.next/server/collection.worker.js", ["150"], { cwd: process.cwd() });
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Note that the `workers/collection.worker.ts` is out of `src/` directory(same level as `next.config.js`:
[image]

When I hit the `/api/hello` endpoint, I get this error in console:

```
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/...projectdir/.next/server/collection.worker.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Heres the generated `.next/server/collection.woker.js`

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: An "eval-source-map" devtool has been used.
 * This devtool is neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file with attached SourceMaps in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
 * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: "production" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).
 */
(self["webpackChunk_N_E"] = self["webpackChunk_N_E"] || []).push([["collection.worker"],{

/***/ "./node_modules/await-sleep/index.js":
/*!*******************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/await-sleep/index.js ***!
  \*******************************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

eval("module.exports = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiLi9ub2RlX21vZHVsZXMvYXdhaXQtc2xlZXAvaW5kZXguanMuanMiLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUEiLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndlYnBhY2s6Ly9fTl9FLy4vbm9kZV9tb2R1bGVzL2F3YWl0LXNsZWVwL2luZGV4LmpzPzVmMmUiXSwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsibW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBtcyA9PiBuZXcgUHJvbWlzZShyZXNvbHZlID0+IHNldFRpbWVvdXQocmVzb2x2ZSwgbXMpKTtcbiJdLCJuYW1lcyI6W10sInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ==\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./node_modules/await-sleep/index.js\n");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./workers/collection.worker.ts":
/*!**************************************!*\
  !*** ./workers/collection.worker.ts ***!
  \**************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"default\": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)\n/* harmony export */ });\nconst sleep = __webpack_require__(/*! await-sleep */ \"./node_modules/await-sleep/index.js\");\nconst paymentId = process.argv[2];\n(async ()=>{\n    // DO WORK HERE\n    console.log(\"doing work \", paymentId);\n    await sleep(10000);\n    console.log(\"Done!\");\n})();\n// tslint:disable-next-line: no-empty\nconst noop = ()=>{};\n/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (noop);\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./workers/collection.worker.ts\n");

/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = (__webpack_exec__("./workers/collection.worker.ts"));
/******/ (_ENTRIES = typeof _ENTRIES === "undefined" ? {} : _ENTRIES)["middleware_collection.worker"] = __webpack_exports__;
/******/ }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your webpack config must be like this

```
if (isServer && config.name === 'server') {
      const oldEntry = config.entry

      return {
        ...config,
        async entry(...args) {
          const entries = await oldEntry(...args)
          return {
            ...entries,
            'collection.worker': path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'workers/collection.worker.ts')
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      return config;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).